# Android: push buttons in from bottom with a delay

Tags: android, animation, button

At a point in my application I got an `Activity` that receives a certain amount of entries from the database. For each entry a button is made and added to the layout. I want that the buttons are "pushed in" from the bottom to the top. I achieved this with a slightly edit of the API sample `push_up_in.xml`. Now what disturbs is that it looks like all `Button`s are pushed in at the same time. I would have a little delay between every push of a `Button` in order to appear more "asynchronuous".

So far, the relevant code looks like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    getDestinationLayout();
    setContentView(linearLayout);
    challengeName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("challengeName");
    context = this;
    datasource = new CustomDataSource(this);
    showGames();    
}

(...)

private void getDestinationLayout(){
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_all_entries, null);
        scrollView = (ScrollView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.rel_all_football);
        buttonHolder = (LinearLayout) scrollView.findViewById(R.id.lin_all_buttonholder);
    }

// is called from showGames() after taking fetched entries, sorted them and so on
private void createAndAddButtons(){
    // the fetched entries are taken in another method
    for(int i=0; i<fetchedEntries.size(); i++){
        (1)
        entryButton = new Button(this) //entryButton is global
        // do some layout stuff
        entryButton.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_up_in));
        (2)
        buttonHolder.add(entryButton);
    }
}
```

Now I thought, no problem, I just put an `Thread.sleep(x)` at point (1) respectively at point (2) to get that effect, but in both cases the start of the `Activity` itself is delayed (it seems for x*`fetchedEntries.size()` millis), and the buttons still are pushed together. In a previous attempt, my onCreate was like

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     challengeName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("challengeName");
     context = this;
     datasource = new CustomDataSource(this);
     showGames();
     setContentView(linearLayout);
}
```

(whereas the `getDestinationLayout()` was inside the `showGames()`), the problem is that I'm first adding the buttons and then call `setContentView(linearLayout)` (what I now think was wrong indeed for coming closer to my goal), but as said also the actual version is not want I wanted. How can I achieve this? Obviously the problem is using the `Thread.sleep(x)`, but on the other hand I don't exactly understand why, since logically the procedure should be

-> `setContentView(linearLayout)`  => Activity is displayed on the Screen
-> LOOP
  -> `Thread.sleep(x)`           => The program waits for x millis
  -> create and add Button     => button i is pushed in
    REPEAT TILL END

**EDIT:**

here is the animation xml file "push_up_in.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.5" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but i think a `Handler` using a `Runnable` will fix your problem.

```
private void createAndAddButtons(){
    Handler h = new Handler();

    //h.post(
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            // the fetched entries are taken in another method
            for(int i=0; i<fetchedEntries.size(); i++){
                entryButton = new Button(this) //entryButton is global
                // do some layout stuff
                entryButton.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.push_up_in));
                buttonHolder.add(entryButton);
            }

        }
    }, 3000);

}
```

Also:

-> setContentView(linearLayout) => Activity is **not** displayed on the Screen

The `Activity` will be displayed after the `onResume` method is called not when you set the content, so you could call the `createAndAddButtons` in the `onResume` of your `Activity` but better would be the `onStart` method because the `onStart` method will only be called when your activity is created.

My advice, use the `Handler` and call the `createAndAddButtons` method in the `onStart` of your `Activity`.

Rolf

Small change that could make your code a bit easier:

Instead of creating a LinearLayout object for the main layout and inflating it and than setting it. Why don't just do it like this?

```
private void getDestinationLayout(){
        setContentView(R.layout.main_all_entries);
        scrollView = (ScrollView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.rel_all_football);
        buttonHolder = (LinearLayout) scrollView.findViewById(R.id.lin_all_buttonholder);
}
```

Comment: But then (so I think at a first glance), there is no delay between the single adding of the buttons, right? Would it be better to put that handler inside the for loop? Or to call some delay function from the handler inside the foor loop? EDIT: just read your edit now, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Ok I did exactly what you suggested, I get all Entries from the onCreate, and from the onStart() I call the createAndAddButtons(). There I put a handler like in your answer above, and in the foor loop I put the Thread.sleep(), but the problem is still here. To test it, I put a Thread.sleep(1000) in, and since in my test db are 15 entries, it sleeps 15 seconds before anything gets displayd. After this 15 seconds, the Activitiy shows up and the buttons are pushed in "together". What could be the one thing I overlooked?

Comment: What happens if you not use the post method of the handler but the postDelayed method? See edit and notice the 3000 second delay before the complete loop is started.

Comment: Ok we're getting closer :-) replacing h.post(...) with h.postDelayed(...) indeed has the effect that the main Activity shows up, and after 3000 millis the buttons are pushed in! So I placed a Thread.sleep(250) in the for loop (250 because then it's really visible if my intention works or not) has the same effect as before, it seems that the amount of the sleep times is totalized as one sleep, and after that the buttons are pushed in

Comment: I tried it too by putting a second handler.postDelayed(...) into the for loop (once instanciating the Handler once outside the for loop, once defining the Handler h2 outside and instanciating in every iteration a new Handler), but no desired effect

Comment: Going to think about this... Could you post your animation xml? So i can recreate a similar situation?

Comment: I pasted in the original question. Thanks a lot, I even tried it with an Async Task doing the for loop, but I'm not that familiar with AsyncTask yet.

Comment: Hello, I tried furthermore with any kind of threads, but unfortunately I haven't found a solution. Do you have any further idea?

Comment: I'm going to try things out, but i'm very busy at the moment ;(